# Is it possible to sub-divide resource/slat hits in a fullcalendar resource timeline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I am evaluating full calendar for an internal scheduling project and I'm currently unable to meet a requirement with respect to event dragging.
We're using typescript and react.

Using the resource timeline view, we've configured employees as resources, made all events full day, but ordered them by priority, the most pressing at the top.

[image: resource timeline - schedule view]

I would like to be able to drag an event, and whilst hovering, for the dragged event to take the priority of the hovered over event, previewing the reprioritised schedule.

By creating a plug-in I'm able to supply eventDragMutationMassagers to mutate my model as desired, however, these are only consumed when a hit is generated, i.e. when the drag enters a new resource row or day column.
Given my limited knowledge of fullcalendar, the solution I envisage would be to cause more hits, i.e. when hovering over another event, however, I am struggling to find a way to do this.

The solution space I have unsuccessfully explored is

1. Extend ResourceTimeLineGrid to provide my own implementation of queryHit, then extend ResourceTimeLineView to initialise my new grid

   1. ResouceTimeLineGrid is not exported
2. Create a new InteractionClass

   1. Writing one from scratch means I'd lose and have to reimplement lots of functionality
   2. Due to exports, I'm unable to extend the existing EventDragging class to call a new hitQuery method
3. Create my own dragging events and plugin to the full calendar events

   1. When I new up an Emitter, it doesn't have the fullcalendar listeners registered, and I can't expose an initialised emitter.

I'd be grateful for a steer on approach and/or any specific helps if possible

Thanks!

Comment: `I am struggling to find a way to do this`...to do what? You've mentioned an implementation idea, but haven't actually explained what the goal is, as far as I can understand.

Comment: Very sorry, I'm on my phone now. I'll edit the question soon. I want to be able to reorder events within a day via drag and drop

Comment: Thanks for the update. There is no functionality for this in fullCalendar. FullCalendar is what it says - a calendar - and therefore it orders events by time, strictly. Priority does not come into it (unless the events have the same start time - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder). But even that doesn't allow for moving them around by dragging. Dragging in fullCalendar is from one time period to another. You could move an event to another day, or another timeslot (in a view which shows hours/mins), but not just arbitrarily make them swap places on some other basis...

Comment: ...so basically what I'm saying is, there's no functionality for what you're asking within fullCalendar. You'd have to write your own dragging and dropping functionality, to replace or extend what fullCalendar provides. (P.S. I'm also tempted to suggest that possibly what you actually need is some sort of project management software, rather than just a calendar.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. We are briefed with creating the aforementioned project management software and wanted to leverage as much fullcalendar as we can as we've had success with the time grid functionality elsewhere in the system.

Answer (score 1):

The desired functionality is not supported by fullcalendar's dragging engine.

In order to achieve this replacing or extending the vanilla software is required.

This should not have been surprising as the intent was to extend a calendar into a scheduling system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).